# Azure DevOps (VSTS) can't find Moq DLLs when running tests

Tags: c#, dll, azure-devops, assembly-binding-redirect, assemblybinding

I keep getting this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Moq, Version=4.2.1507.118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

It compiles fine in my project, and all of my Moq Nuget packages are set to version 4.2.1507.118. I don't have any binding redirects for Moq.

By the way, is there any way to turn assembly binding logging on for a VSTS hosted agent?

**Log files**:
[Here's my build step log output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q4bJEzxmkZVhV6l1jRm07ZnymxnPjZJ2/view?usp=sharing)
[Here's my test step log output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yhXwIOYFtVfQpIveYI8QOeBSyw2gXwRx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you restoring your NuGet packages prior to building?

Comment: Yes, I am @DanielMann. (My name is extremely similar to yours -- Daniel <prefix>mann, and I'm an awful guitarist too.)

Comment: Can you share the logs of Nuget restore task?